# Can integers be divisible by real numbers?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, definition, divisibility

I have searched for many definitions of divisibility and they all seem to go like this:

Let $a, b \in \mathbb{Z}$ then $b$ is divisible by $a$ if there exists $c \in \mathbb{Z} : b = ac$.

Is divisibility defined only between integers? Is it incorrect to say that 3 is divisible by 1.5?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisibility_(ring_theory) might be of interest

Comment: Why the downvote? This is a perfectly good question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may generalize the concept of divisibility to general [rings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)). So you have to be specific. Usually we talk about divisibility in terms of $\Bbb{Z}$ because if we introduce $\Bbb{Q}$ or $\Bbb{R}$ things get boring, everything divides everything (except weirdness around $0$)!

So if you say " $3$ is divisible by $1.5$", you have to specify. Are you in $\Bbb{Z}$? Then $1.5$ doesn't exist! Are you in $\Bbb{Q}$? Then yes, because everything divides everything then! (again except issues with $0$)

For example if you consider the ring of polynomials with coefficients in $\Bbb{R}$, $x+2$ divides $x^2-4$. There are other examples of divisibility in strange rings.

Comment: So then the reason $a, b, c$ are chosen to be in $\mathbb{Z}$ is to avoid problems with everything dividing everything? And in that case $1.5 \in \mathbb{R}$ divides $3 \in \mathbb{R}$ but $1.5 \in \mathbb{R}$ does not divide $3 \in \mathbb{Z}$ is this correct?

Comment: @K.R.S. I wouldn't call it a problem, just...boring. You are not quite right with your last statement. Divisibility only makes sense relative to some set, and both terms have to be from the same set. If you're in $\Bbb{R}$, $1.5$ divides $3$. If you're in $\Bbb{Z}$ you don't even know what $1.5$ is!

Comment: I have a feeling that the same person who downvoted me is the same person that downvoted you. Your question is totally reasonable and very interesting! @K.R.S.

Comment: But 3 is evenly divisible by 1.5, while not evenly divisible by 1.1.  Is that the correct terminology?